# Copied site has wrong menu URL behaviour

Tags: menus

I copied working WP site to a new dir for a theme redesign, created a separate db, change all old site urls to the new address. Now when I use menu it goes to the old site location. Rewrite rules are the same. Whats wrong?

Comment: When you said you changed all old site URLs to the new address, how did you do that? Did you use an SQL query? If so that would explain the issue

Comment: No. I opened text editor and changed old site name https://oldsitename.com for a new dir https://oldsitename.com/1/   

Thx!

Comment: Ooh, you have to change things in the database to change a sites URL

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Search and Replace plugin (I like "Better Search and Replace") to replace in the database all instances of the olddomain name with the new one. This will fix media links, and anything else that has the olddomain name.

You could do it manually with some SQL queries, and going into the menu area of the new site, but the plugin will be much faster. (Backup your database first, of course. But I've used the above plugin on several sites without problems. )

Comment: Doing it with SQL queries will break any serialised PHP values, causing the site to crash